# I have two problems converting data using Perl?

Tags: perl

1. I want to convert this input `{111,222},{333,444},{555,666}` so that the output be like this `111;222;333;444;555;666`. The same thing goes for `{111,222},{333,444}` to `111;222;333;444` and `{111,222}` to `111;222`.
2. I want to convert this date format from `2019-11-12 15:25:19` to `11/12/2019 15:25:19` and `2019-11-04T15:26:11.000+00:00` to `11/12/2019 15:25:19`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  Since the title mentions Perl and there's no mention of C, I've removed the C tag.  What have you tried?  They both seem amenable to handling the data as strings and using the `s///` operation (several times, perhaps) to transform the input into the output.  More fiddly than very difficult.

Comment: if you have two questions, you should create two questions, not one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use a simple script like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl -pl
   s/^\{//;
   s/\}$//;
   s/\}?,\{?/;/g;
   ```

   The shebang line says read input lines and print the modified form of each one (`-p`) and handle line endings automatically (`-l`).

   The first `s///` removes a leading `{`.  The second removes a trailing `}`.  The last replaces `},{` and `,` with `;` across the line.
2. You could use a simple script like this (assuming that you really want `2019-11-04T15:26:11.000+00:00` mapped to `11/04/2019 15:26:11` and not the other value which is 8 days bar 52 seconds after the input value):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl -pl
   s%(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)[T ](\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*%$2/$3/$1 $4%;
   ```

   The shebang line is the same as before.  The regex looks for 4 digits, dash, 2 digits, dash, 2 digits, blank or `T`, an `hh:mm:ss` string and stray junk and reformats it in the correct sequence.

Between them, they produce the desired results.

Of course, this being Perl, TMTOWTDI — timtoady, or "there's more than one way to do it":

```
$ cat data
{111,222},{333,444},{555,666}
{111,222},{333,444}
{111,222}
$ cat data.2
2019-11-12 15:25:19
2019-11-04T15:26:11.000+00:00
$ perl -pl -e 's/^\{//; s/\}$//; s/\}?,\{?/;/g; s%(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)[T ](\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*%$2/$3/$1 $4%;' data data.2
111;222;333;444;555;666
111;222;333;444
111;222
11/12/2019 15:25:19
11/04/2019 15:26:11
$
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I am a beginner in perl
$data="{111,222},{333,444},{555,666}";
$data=s/^\{//;
$data=s/\}$//;
$data=s/\}?,\{?/;/g;
print $data;

the program will not work

Comment: Next time, please try to produce something — an _honest_ attempt to solve the problem.  And then ask for help with the problems you face with your attempt.  I probably shouldn't have posted this answer.  Note that `\d\d` is shorter than `\d{2}` which achieves the same result in the regexes — and is why I wrote that out.  I probably could use `(\d\d(:\d\d){2})` to shorten the hh:mm:ss match — or even `(\d\d(?::\d\d){2})` — but that would probably confuse you more than it would help you.

Comment: Your script uses assignments `=` where it should use the regex [binding operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) `=~`.  If you use: `perl -le '$data="{111,222},{333,444},{555,666}"; $data=~s/^\{//; $data=~s/\}$//; $data=~s/\}?,\{?/;/g; print $data;'` it produces the requisite output.  Or better, use a little more white space: `perl -le '$data = "{111,222},{333,444},{555,666}"; $data =~ s/^\{//; $data =~ s/\}$//; $data =~ s/\}?,\{?/;/g; print $data;'`

Comment: You can format code in comments using backticks before and after the code.  For example ```…`code`…```.  You can use one, two or three backticks at each end — that fragment used three backticks around the ellipsis, backtick, 'code', backtick, ellipsis material.

Answer (score 0):

Just transliterating sequences of non-digits to `;`:

```
$data =~ y/0-9/;/cs;
```